# How to add custom attributes in GitHub issues?

Tags: github, issue-tracking

We are trying to use GitHub for issue tracking in one of our projects and while its very simply to use, we aren't sure its powerful enough at the same time to fulfil our needs to organize our issue management since we can't find a way to customize it.

**Question: Is it possible to add custom attributes in GitHub for issue tracking, search/sort and export the list of issues with those attributes? For example, we'd like to add and use following attributes:**

1. **External Issue ID:** There is an external list of issues/change requests maintained by a separate group that we need to associate
   our issues with and need a field to specify the external issue ID.
2. **Priority:** so that we can easily discuss and prioritize what we want to tackle first
3. **Severity:** to identify impact on the system
4. **Type of Issue:** Bug, Change Request, New Requirement
5. **Class:** Performance, Security, Function, Compliance etc.
6. **Source:** to track whether issue was reported by a specific customer (which could be in hundreds), end user, internal team,
   partner etc.
7. **Date Opened:** I think this is maintained internally by GitHub but not exposed anywhere in the UI
8. **Date Closed**
   etc.

We understand some of these can be implemented with labels but there would be too many of them to assign and they do not allow exclusivity (for example you can only specify one priority  - high, medium, or low assigning - to an issue)

Any ideas if and how this can be implemented in GitHub?

If not, any recommendations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned already, this so far is only done by using labels, for example the way i do priority is having multiple labels:

Priority: Blocker

Priority: High

....

Yes, unfortunately this feature is not intended to exclusively select one value per category as these are labels.

There is a github issue that proposes a new feature to GitHub so that we can have a Priority attribute in every GitHub issue right here

https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/472

Not sure about all the other custom attributes, but maybe this would be a good start for your idea.

Comment: I have multiple such labels, like `Priority:<LEVEL>`, `Component:<TYPE>`, `Status:<LEVEL>`, `Effort:<LEVEL>`, `Reject:<TYPE>`, `Type:<BUG/FEATURE>`, `Phase:<LEVEL>`. And in order to lave them display in LEVEL order instead of alphabetically, I prepend a number to the LEVEL name. I use a tool to copy these labels from project to project: http://www.dorukdestan.com/github-label-manager/

Answer (score 3):

Update June 2021: you could use custom fields for those attributes!

> ### [New beta features within GitHub Issues, with better ways to plan, track, and manage projects](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-06-23-whats-new-with-github-issues/).

> Read more on the [GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/features/issues) or in the [FAQ](http://github.com/features/issues#faq).
> ✨ NEW – Project planning for developers
>
> Available in limited public beta
>
> Built like a spreadsheet, [project tables](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/trying-out-the-new-projects-experience/about-projects) give you a live canvas to filter, sort, and group issues and pull requests.
>
> **Tailor them to your needs with custom fields and saved views.**
>
> [Sign up for the beta now](https://github.com/features/issues).

That includes:

> - Extend issues with custom fields with support for text, number, date and single-select types
> - Change custom field values right from the issues sidebar
> - **Filter, sort, and group by any field**

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a way to create custom parameters. You may be able to do this by storing the data inline in the text of the issue and then parsing that issue text programatically, but that's kind of a hack.

For instance, if you wanted to link a GitHub issue to an internal bug tracker like JIRA, just use the JIRA issue name in the text of the GitHub issue and then write a regular expression to parse it back out. This requires a little bit of extra plumbing on top of GitHub.

Date opened and closed are available in the API. See [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/).

(Incidentally, I'd note that the lack of customisation and complexity is a key *feature* of GitHub's issue tracking system: it is designed for developers, not project managers who want to tweak it into a confusing JIRA-like hellscape of misery.)

Answer (score 0):

Use tags

Most of the time you can put the kinds of things you want in the body of the issue as text or use a tag for things like priority. You only need to set priority if it's not the default one.